# php separate array label and values

Tags: php, arrays

i have arrays like this

```
Array( 
    [0] => Array( 
            [member_name] => hohoho 
            [member_type] => SUPPLIER 
            [interest] => Array( 
                            [0] => HOLIDAY 
                            [1] => MOVIES) 
    ), 
    [1] => Array( 
            [member_name] => jajaja 
            [member_validity] => 13/12/2001 
            [interest] => Array(
                            [0] => SPORTS 
                            [1] => FOODS) 
    )
)
```

how can I put the array keys and items in a separate variable? for example, i want to have something like

```
$keyholder[0] = member_name,member_type,interest
$keyholder[1] = member_name,member_validity,interest
$itemholder[0] = hohoho,SUPPLIER,{HOLIDAY,MOVIES}
$itemholder[1] = jajaja,13/12/2001,{SPORTS,FOODS}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `array_keys()` and `array_values()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 1):

You can cycle through an array and get the key and values like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{
   echo $key." - ".$val."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyholder=array();
$itemholder=array();
foreach($original_array as $values){
    $inner_keys=array();
    $inner_values=array();
    foreach($values as $key=>$value){
        $inner_keys[]=$key;
        $inner_values[]=$value;        
    }
    $keyholder[]=$inner_keys;
    $itemholder[]=$inner_values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
$cnt = count($original);
$keys = array();
$items = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
   $keys[] = array_keys($original[$i]);
  $items[] = array_values($original[$i]);
```

}